# React: server side rendering, Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: <!doctype html>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side

I am trying to render the whole page in `React` only then sending it to the browser. I am getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: `<!doctype html>`

The line that is producing this error is `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(el);`:

```
fs.readFile('./public/index.html',"utf8", function (err, data){
    /*res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();*/
    var el = React.createElement(data);
    console.log("React element was successfully created!");
-----> var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(el);
    res.send(html);
  });
```

The `html` file looks the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
    <title>React App</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix the error? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried to do the following:

```
var mainData = prepareDataForScatterChart(result);
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(`<App 
  mainData=${mainData}/>`);
  fs.readFile('./public/index.html',"utf8", function (err, data){
  const document = data.replace(/<div id="app"><\/div>/, `<div 
  id="app">${html}</div>`);
  res.send(document);
```

The error is gone, but after I load the page there are errors that mean that the data was not passed to the `App`.

> Update

I got it working on the server by adding `babel-node`, but browser still somehow is not getting the data. So, in the `App` I am printing out the `mainData` and it is there in the `node` console, but in browser it is shown as `undefined`. Here is the code that I am using now:

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App mainData={mainData}/>);
```

Comment: You're trying to render that HTML page as JSX. That's why `<!doctype html>` is invalid (because that's invalid JSX). You need to import your bundle into the server and render the root component, using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)`. [Here's an example](https://css-tricks.com/server-side-react-rendering/)

Comment: Here's an example https://github.com/pizza-r0b/isomorphic-redux-react-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/server/index.js - the above states you need to pass a valid component to createElement

Comment: I am having now trouble with passing the parameters to the `App` element now. I do not know `Redux`... Could I just use `React`?

Comment: @Sidney Actually with the `const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App/>);` I am getting an error, it can not parse it.

Comment: If you use JSX in your server code, it needs to be transpiled. The example I linked shows how to set that up through Webpack and Babel.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now, however, the data is somehow is in `App` that is on the server, but not in the `App` that gets to the browser. I have `console.log(this.props.mainData["1"]);` in `App` and first it is printed on the server correctly in `node` console, but then browser prints it out as `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
// import your app component containing the html structure.
import App from './App.jsx';
// Get your data as required.
const mainData = {}; 

res.send(
  renderToString(`<!DOCTYPE html>${<App mainData={mainData}/>}`)
);
```

Using `fs` to load a static html file and using `replace()` are unnecessary unless you have compelling reasons to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the streaming variant.

You can do this (working with `express` and `react-dom`, but should work with any stream):

```js
function streamingRender(code, res, component) {
  res.status(code)
  res.write("<!DOCTYPE html>")
  renderToNodeStream(component).pipe(res)
}
```